# Select rows based on multiple conditions in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a table with 1 million+ records like this:

[image: ![enter image description here]

My aim is to get records that have status N, excluding those records that do not have the latest (wrt date column) entry as Y.
I'm looking for something like this:

[image]

Here entries with status=N are id=123,129,128. The latest entry associated with order 129 is 'Y' so we exclude it from our output. In other words, because 129 had status N previously, but on its new run on the next day, the status changed to Y. So I do not need 129 for further processing.

I tried with nested SELECT queries and join but was unable to get the right combination. Kindly suggest a suitable solution.

Comment: Latest in what grouping? By date?

Comment: What have you already tried and where exactly are you stuck? Are you familiar with ["top 1 per group"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column) solutions?

Comment: Write a subquery that gets the latest row for each date. Join that with the original table, and filter to `latest.status = 'Y'`

Comment: @Barmar - Good point! I somehow immediately assumed `by id` .

Comment: Updated the question as per recommendation.

Comment: *excluding those records that do not have the latest (wrt date column) entry as Y* means: "including those records that have the latest (wrt date column) entry as Y". Then why do you exclude 129?

Comment: @forpas ... because 129 had status N previously. But on its new run on the next day, the status has been changed to Y. So I do not need 129 for further processing.

Comment: Edit your question and clarify. Your requirement is unclear as it is.

Comment: I'm guessing that `L` is a reference to an Indian word. Please use measurements that everyone understands.

Comment: Edits are done as per suggestions.

Comment: Still the same comment, *Lakh* is not used or understood globally. Please don't use local words here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using window function `row_number()` to order data by date, then we check if the latest row of the status_id is 'N' or not.

```
   with cte as (
      select t.*, row_number() over (partition by id order by Date ) as row_id
      from mytable t
      order by id
    ),
    cte2 as (
      select id, max(row_id) as max_row_id
      from cte
      group by id
    )
    select c.id, c.Date, c.status
    from cte c
    inner join cte2 c2 on c.row_id = c2.max_row_id and c.id = c2.id
    where c.status = 'N';
```

For old versions of mysql/mariadb :

```
select t.id, t.Date, t.status
from mytable t
inner join (
  select id, max(Date) as max_Date
  from mytable
  group by id
) as c on c.max_Date = t.Date and c.id = t.id
where t.status = 'N';
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/RJSxE_bs)

Comment: What does c and c2 point to in the last section of above query? These variables aren't declared previously in query

Comment: C and c2 are tables alias, https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-alias/

Comment: Can you update this query for SQL 5.6

Comment: Can you check my update